# EF 6 Code First Generated From Database adding Releationship

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing database that I used the nuget feature 'Code First From Database'

For the most part it seemed to have worked very well.  However, it did not pick up all of the key relationships that the database has.

I have a table called Sessions and a table called Responses.  The Responses table has a field for SessionId.  Now in the old EDMX model file I had a 1:* relationship between Sessions and Responses.  This way I could do `foundSession.Responses` to get a list of the Responses for that session.

The Code First From Database did not create the Session.Responses relationship.  I've added an ICollection to the Session Model.  I suspect that I need to also add how that relationship is set up in the 'OnModelCreating' method.

I tried to do something like:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Session>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Responses)
            .WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("Sessions").MapLeftKey("Id").MapRightKey("SessionId"));
```

But that didn't work.  It gave me an error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.Sessions1'."

I was trying to base it off of another line in that same method:

```
          modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Users)
            .WithMany(e => e.Roles)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("RoleUser").MapLeftKey("Roles_Id").MapRightKey("Users_Id"));
```

but that is a many to many relationship.  I don't seem to see any that are 1:many.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how to do it with the Fluent API, but you could do it this way using Data Annotations:

In your `Session` class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
```

In your `Response` class:

```
[ForeignKey("MySession")]
public int SessionID { get; set; }

public virtual Session MySession { get; set; }
```

Comment: I get this error:  The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SessionId' on type 'Outcomes_Report_Engine.Models.DAL.DbResponse' is not valid. The navigation property 'Sessions' was not found on the dependent type 'Outcomes_Report_Engine.Models.DAL.DbResponse'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

Comment: Did you put the navigation property on it?

Comment: Is that in addition to the two chunks of code in your solution?

Comment: No, that should be what I've written in. Make sure that for testing this you aren't using any Fluent API that tries to do the same thing.

Comment: That did it! I was missing that second line in the Responses Class public virtual Session MySession { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to create the one-to-many relationship using Fluent Api:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Response>().
   HasRequired(e => e.Session).
   WithMany(s=>s.Responses).
   HasForeignKey(m => m.SessionId);
```

Comment: Is product supposed to be 'Session'?  What is .Parent supposed to be?


            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().
   HasRequired(e => e.Responses).
HasForeignKey(m => m.SessionId);

.HasForeignKey isn't resolve because the HasRequired e.Responses is an ICollection I set up in the Session Class

Comment: If I change Product to Session, then I can't do the line below it e.Session

Comment: the configuration that you show in your comment is not the same  as mine. Did you try my configuration?

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().
         HasRequired(e => e.Session).
         WithMany(s => s.Responses).
         HasForeignKey(m => m.SessionId);    Does not work because 'e' in this case is a session so I can't do e.session

Comment: But why you want to change Product per Session? The configuration that you show me in the comment is wrong

Comment: I've solved it without using the Fluent API (see above)

Comment: In the HasRequired method you configure the one part of your relationship, so, you need to specify the Session navegation property that have Response. In the HasMany method you especify the ICollection<Response> that have Session.

Comment: Hello @Scottingham, it didn't work at first because I did not realize that I had to change modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() for modelBuilder.Entity<Response>(). I copied that piece of code from one of my project and I tried to adapt it to your escenario ;)